# Does the Minlos theorem work for real-valued cases as well?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ be the Frechet space of real-valued smooth periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Here, $\mathbb{T}^3$ is the $3$-dimensional torus.

Let us define a real-valued functional $\Phi$ on $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ as
\begin{equation}
\Phi(f):=\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{T}^3} f^2(x) d^3x \Bigr) \text{ for } f \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})
\end{equation}

Then, it seems to me that $\Phi$ satisfies all properties required by a characteristic functional of some Gaussian measure on the dual space $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$ of $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})$, so that there exists a unique Gaussian measure $\mu$ on the dual space such that
\begin{equation}
\Phi(f)=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{R})} e^{i T(f)}d\mu(T)
\end{equation}
by the Minlos theorem.

However, the complex exponential on the right side of the second equation concerns me. I searched for references but no book tells clearly about the case when everything is over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$. In fact, they don't seem to clearly state which case they are dealing with..

Could anyone please clarify for me?